# What is the fix for black screen with cursor after Ubuntu 18 update?

Tags: updates, nomodeset

I have a Asus X510A and I recently updated Ubuntu 16 to 18
After the first boot attempt it landed on a black screen with just the cursor. 
I have looked at forums and all and the most suggested nomodeset option for disabling the graphic drivers does not work. Legacy versions also land on the same black screen. Also I have not seen any of the tutorials where the black screen actually shows the cursor.

Can some one point me in the right direction for a fix without losing my data?
Thanks.